# C# Daemon for reading large amount of files

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, filesystemwatcher

I will start by giving some context first

### Introduction

I am creating a program that will run continuously on a server. Part of the program is the ability to send automated mails to different representatives. The content of these mails will be automatically put in a folder, so the program needs to be notified when new content is ready and **read the text** that is in this file. However this is not a problem and I already have my solution for this.

### The Problem

It is possible that there will be multiple files placed in the folder at the same time, here is when my program cannot handle it. I get the following exception :

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file *GENERATEDFILE* because it is being used by another process.

As soon as the program tries to read a file that has been put in the folder,it will give me this exception, and I cannot wrap my head around why it does

### What I have already

So I have a method that creates the FileSystemWatcher like this :

```
public void Watch(){
_watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
_watcher.NotifyFilters =  NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                          NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                          NotifyFilters.FileName |
                          NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
_watcher.Created += OnCreated

}

private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e){
//read the file that got created here and pass the content to an object that wille handle it further
}
```

So pretty easy, we create a FileSystemWatcher, we attach some NotifyFilters to it and the OnCreated event

## I have tried the following

In the OnCreated method i have tried the following

1. `File.ReadAllText(filePath)`
   I would assume this was the standard way of reading files, however this does not work
2. `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath)){
       String line = sr.ReadToEnd();}`
   From microsoft
3. I have tried `Thread.Sleep(5000)` to see if it needs some time, no effect
4. I have tried using the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class that enters the readlock everytime i start reading, this solution sometimes works, but is not good enough to guarantee
5. I have tried putting each file in a list, then iterating over that list but still gives me the same exception

### The Question

Is there any way to handle the event where multiple files get put in the folder at the same time?

Comment: Note about doing "too much" in your event handler: _"[Keep your event handling code as short as possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)"_.  Because otherwise you may _"[miss an event when the buffer size is exceeded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)"_.  Consider queuing a job in your `OnCreated()` rather than attempting to process the file then and there.  Otherwise, jolly nicely formatted question. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about catching the exception and setting a timer to retry later?

Answer (score 0):

**The Cause**
File created event happens when the file is created, not when it is finished writing out.

**A Solution**
Consider adding a task for the processing logic.
When the file is created, the filename/path gets handed to a method that runs in a task that keeps retrying.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private ConcurrentQueue<string> _filesProcessQueue;
        private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

        [TestMethod]
        public void Watch()
        {
            _filesProcessQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
            _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
            {
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                               NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                               NotifyFilters.FileName |
                               NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
            };
            _watcher.Created += OnCreated;
        }

        private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a task for reading the file after the lock is released
            Task.Run(() => ProcessFileQueue(e.FullPath));
        }

        private void ProcessFileQueue(string fullPath)
        {
            bool processSuccess = false;
            // TODO put terminator logic in here to stop retrying forever
            while (processSuccess == false)
            {
                // TODO try process the file and return success/fail
                processSuccess = true; // Continue to next file
                //processSuccess = false; // Retry the same file

                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // Delay 5 seconds before retrying the file.
            }
        }
    }
}
```